# Changing header from a logo img to site title

Tags: php, html, wordpress, header, themes

I am trying to change my site header logo from an img to my site name (it would just take my site name from Wordpress settings).  I can't figure out how to change this, and I feel like it is just a simple fix.  Does anyone have any solutions?

inc/header/style5.php

```html
<?php 
 $header_color = ot_get_option('header_color', 'light');
?>
<!-- Start Header -->
<header class="header style5 <?php echo esc_attr($header_color); ?>" role="banner">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="small-2 columns text-left mobile-icon-holder">
   <a href="#" data-target="open-menu" class="mobile-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="small-8 large-12 columns logo">
   <div id="menu_width">
    <?php if (ot_get_option('thb_logo')) { $logo = ot_get_option('thb_logo'); } else { $logo = THB_THEME_ROOT. '/assets/img/logo.png'; } ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" class="logolink">
     <img src="<?php echo esc_url($logo); ?>" class="logoimg" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"/>
    </a>
    <nav class="menu-holder">
     <?php if (has_nav_menu('nav-menu')) { ?>
       <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'nav-menu', 'depth' => 3, 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'sf-menu style3', 'walker' => new thb_MegaMenu_tagandcat_Walker ) ); ?>
     <?php } else if ( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) { ?>
         <ul class="sf-menu style3">
             <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Please assign a menu', 'goodlife' ); ?></a></li>
         </ul>
     <?php } ?>
    </nav>
    <?php do_action( 'thb_secondary'); ?>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-2 columns text-right mobile-share-holder">
   <div>
   <?php do_action( 'thb_quick_search' ); ?>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
<!-- End Header -->
```

And I think the only part of this code I have to edit is this little section?  I just can't figure out how to edit it correctly.

```html
    <?php if (ot_get_option('thb_logo')) { $logo = ot_get_option('thb_logo'); } else { $logo = THB_THEME_ROOT. '/assets/img/logo.png'; } ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" class="logolink">
     <img src="<?php echo esc_url($logo); ?>" class="logoimg" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"/>
    </a>
```

Comment: If a majority of your code is PHP why do you switch back and forth so much between PHP and HTML? Why not write it totally in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to change:

```
<img src="<?php echo esc_url($logo); ?>" class="logoimg" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"/>
```

to simply:

```
<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
```